# How to structure database, multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I feel like this may be a bit of a unique problem, but hopefully someone out there has come across a similar situation.

My application uses this database table:

[DT table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXqo.png)

The issue is with Field1 - 9.
Depending on how the user decides to set up their instance of the app there can be any number of fields used (from 0 - 9). The information for these are held in this Table:

[Field Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxelY.png)

So for this example there are only to be two fields. And when a record is created for the DT table, field 1 and 2 will have data entered and all other field columns will be NULL. Obviously this isn't good practice, as for one, if a field name was changed in the future, all previous data wouldn't make sense.

I've been trying to think of a way to structure it differently. all I can think of is somehow when a DT record is created it will hold foreign keys to the fields that were used, but it seems that it's not possible to have multiple foreign keys in one column.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to normalize this would be to factor out the repeating fields to a separate table, where you would have one entry per field with DT_id as a foreign key to the DT table.

**DT Table**:
ID
Start
End
...

**DT_field table**:
ID
DT_id *(foreign key)*
Value